# Regex Expression between two string

Tags: regex

I need to help for Regex expression characters between two string. If not found second character output will be all sentence after first character.

First character = "-p-"
Second character = "?"

```
-p-sentence? => output = sentence
-p-sentence => output = sentence.
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this regex, you can get result with group 1:

`-p-(.*?)(?:\?|$)`

See result [here](https://regex101.com/r/nYdsOQ/1)

Comment: Hello, I need another things too. If String like "-p-?", I dont want any match. How can I do that.

Comment: This is because the regex assumes that the searched string ends with a `?`. In this case, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Expected behavior, When start with "-p-" and ends with "?" and there is nothing between them should be no match.

Comment: With this version, the regex expects at least one character between `-p-`and `?` : `-p-([^?]+?)(?:\?|$)`

Comment: Thank you. It is working.